# GitHub w/ BlueJ, I can Checkout a Project but cannot Commit Updates(or any project)

Tags: java, git, github, bluej

I am new to GitHub & repositories but have done a lot of reading and trying to get a grasp on how it all works.

I am working on a group project via BlueJ. I created an account and a repository on GitHub. Through BlueJ using Team Settings, I have entered all of the required information. I am able to checkout and work on locally projects that are in my repository. However, every time I attempt to Commit a change, I get the following error:

`svn: Malformed URL'/ccubinski/GNN/!svn/wbl/61467cd6-3e01-0010-93Od-b169ec9ecee6/2'`

I do not have any Git stuff installed locally, as from what I understand(and may very well be wrong), is that I should not have to have anything additional besides BlueJ in order to interact with GitHub.

Comment: Hint: use a git terminal. (1) Lots of IDEs provide git support in their own way, but using a terminal is IDE independent. (2) It is easier to find answers to future git questions in terms of terminal commands (vs button/menu clicks).

Comment: ***Note**: This question was originally asked before BlueJ had support for Git repositories. Versions released after March 8, 2017 should not have this issue.*

Answer (score 1):

BlueJ doesn't support git, only cvs and subversion (svn).

Comment: And [adding it doesn't seem to be a a high-priority issue](http://bugs.bluej.org/bluej/ticket/363).

Answer (score 0):

## How to add Git Repositories in BlueJ

**For BlueJ 4.0 or higher:**

Go to **Tools->Preferences** and enable **"Show teamwork controls"**. You can then make a local clone of the project through **Tools->Team->Checkout**. A box similar to the one below should show up. make sure to select "Git" as your server type.

[image: BlueJ team settings screen]

---

**For BlueJ 3.1.7 or lower:**

Git repositories are not supported for versions of BlueJ released before March 8, 2017.

**[Download the latest version from bluej.org](https://www.bluej.org/)**

---

**For more information about using Git with BlueJ, [refer to the official BlueJ Git Tutorial](https://www.bluej.org/tutorial/git/).**